# How do I list all labels in my neo4j database using the java api?

Tags: java, neo4j

I'd like to list all labels in my neo4j database.

For example, in my site, I have 'songs' which I'd like to tag with labels such as 'jazz', 'classical', 'hiphop', or 'funk'. I can do this, but then I also want to let users know which tags already exist by returning all the labels (aka tags) in my database.

I could use nodes for tags instead, but I thought tagging would be a good use case for labels. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`GlobalGraphOperations.getAllLabels()`](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/javadocs/org/neo4j/tooling/GlobalGraphOperations.html#getAllLabels()) is your friend.